# Equivalence of definitions of a vector bundle

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

Let $n\in\mathbb N$, let $E,B$ be topological spaces and let $p:E\to B$ be a continuous map. For every $b\in B$, let $p^{-1}(b)$ be equipped with the structure of an $n$-dimensional real vector space. Regard the two following definitions of a vector bundle:

1. $p:E\to B$ is called a vector bundle if for every $b\in B$ there is an open neighbourhood $U\subset B$ of $b$ and a homoeomorphism $\phi: p^{-1}(U)\to U\times\mathbb R^n$ such that $\pi_1\circ\phi=p|_{p^{-1}(U)}$, and for all $y\in U$ the map $\pi_2\circ\phi: p^{-1}(y)\to\mathbb R^n$ is linear.
2. $p:E\to B$ is called a vector bundle if it is a fibre bundle with fibre $\mathbb R^n$ and the maps
   $$+:E\times_B E\to E, (x,y)\mapsto x+y$$
   $$\cdot:\mathbb R\times E\to E, (t,x)\mapsto tx$$
   are continuous.

Are these definitions equivalent?

If not, are the analogues in the category of smooth manifolds equivalent?

Edit: Removed a superfluous condition in the second definition.

Comment: Where did you find definition 2?

Comment: I did not find the second definition anywhere. It seemed natural to me that, if a fibre bundle has these properties, its local trivialisations could be tweaked to be fibre-wise linear, at least in the smooth case. I cannot quite show that the definitions are equivalent and I actually assume that they are not, but I cannot think of a counter example.

Comment: The definitions of $+$ and $\cdot$ are not clear to me. Are they defined pointwise over $B$ so that $e_1 + e_2$ is defined if $p(e_1) = p(e_2) =: b$ and then $e_1 + e_2 = \phi^{-1}(b, \pi_2\circ\phi(e_1) + \pi_2\circ\phi(e_2))$?

Comment: $E\times_B E=\{(e_1,e_2)\in E\times E|p(e_1)=p(e_2)\}$ is the fibre product of $E$ with itself with respect to $p$. For every $b\in B$, $p^{-1}(b)$ is already an $n$-dimensional real vector space. The maps $+$ and $\cdot$ are defined through these vector space operations. A priori, a vector bundle according to definition 2 need not admit local trivialisations that are linear in each fibre.